# sed: mass converting epochs amongst random other text

Tags: bash, sed

Centos / Linux
Bash

I have a log file, which has lots of text in and epoch numbers all over the place.  I want to replace all epochs whereever they are into readable date/time.

I've been wanting to this via sed, as that seems the tool for the job.  I can't seem to get the replacement part of sed to actually parse the variable(epoch) to it for conversion.

Sample of what I'm working with...

```
echo "Some stuff 1346474454 And not working" \
| sed 's/1[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/'"`bpdbm -ctime \&`"'/g'
Some stuff 0 = Thu Jan  1 01:00:00 1970 And not working
```

The bpdbm part will convert a supplied epoch variable into useful date.  Like this..

```
bpdbm -ctime 1346474454
1346474454 = Sat Sep  1 05:40:54 2012
```

So how do i get the "found" item to be parsed into a command.  As i don't seem to be able to get it to work.

Any help would be lovely.  If there is another way, that would be cool...but i suspect sed will be quickest.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: run this with `set -vx` to see why it is not working. Sed has to process the line of data before it "knows" the value of '&', the cmd-subtitution would have to be delayed until the last thing, but it is likely the first thing getting proccessed. You can do this easily in awk. Your faith in sed is touching ;-). Good luck!

Comment: Well, yeah...like to try and keep to sed and awk where possible.  Will have another play with Sed tomorrow, i haven't give up on a sed-based resolution

Answer (score 7):

> that seems the tool for the job

No, it is not. `sed` can use `&` only itself, there is no way how to make it an argument to a command. You need something more powerful, e.g. Perl:

```
perl -pe 'if ( ($t) = /(1[0-9]+)/ ) { s/$t/localtime($t)/e }'
```

Comment: That worked perfectly for me for parsing XML that had epoch time into human readable: `cat inputfile.xml | perl -pe 'if ( ($t) = /(1[0-9]+)/ ) { s/$t/localtime($t)/e }' > outputfile.xml`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with GNU sed, the input:

**infile**

```
Some stuff 1346474454 And not working
```

GNU sed supports `/e` parameter which allows for piping command output into pattern space, one way to take advantage of this with `bpdbm`:

```
sed 's/(.*)(1[0-9]{9})(.*)/echo \1 $(bpdbm -ctime \2) \3/e' infile
```

Or with `coreutils` `date`:

```
sed 's/(.*)(1[0-9]{9})(.*)/echo \1 $(date -d @\2) \3/e' infile
```

**output with date**

```
Some stuff Sat Sep 1 06:40:54 CEST 2012 And not working
```

To get the same output as with `bpdbm`:

```
sed 's/(.*)(1[0-9]{9})(.*)/echo "\1$(date -d @\2 +\"%a %b %_d %T %Y\")\3"/e' infile
```

**output**

```
Some stuff Sat Sep  1 06:40:54 2012 And not working
```

Note, this only replaces the last epoch found on a line. Re-run if there are more.